# Remove (if it exists) a 'class' attribute from 'a' html element in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove a 'class' attribute from 'a' html element in PHP.

Example 1:

```
<p class="red">Link: <a href="http://www.google.com" style ="margin: 0px">google</a>.</p>
```

Result:

```
<p class="red">Link: <a href="http://www.google.com" style ="margin: 0px">google</a>.</p>
```

---

Example 2:

```
<p class="red">Link: <a href="http://www.google.com" class =  "link" style="margin: 0px"  >google</a>.</p>
```

Result:

```
<p class="red">Link: <a href="http://www.google.com" style="margin: 0px"  >google</a>.</p>
```

Comment: You don't need php or regex. You need javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Comment: @aj_r, I need do it in server side, examples are PHP strings. I need do it using regex.

Comment: @Amparo: Yes, you should do it in PHP. No, you [should not use regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572)

Comment: Is the just a string or in an HTML document?

Comment: @hwnd It is a string

Comment: Why not use substr then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expressions are nice. I love them, though they'll act like naughty girls in the case of being misused. So I'm going to do it with pretty **DomDocument**:

```
<?php
    $html = <<< EOT
    <p class="red">Link: <a href="http://www.google.com" class =  "link" style="margin: 0px"  >google</a>.</p>
EOT;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach($a as $tag)
      $tag->removeAttribute('class');
    $html = $dom->saveHTML();
    echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(<a(?:\s+\w+\s*=\s*(?P<quote>["']).*?(?P=quote))*)\s+class\s*=\s*(?P<q>["']).*?(?P=q)
```

replace with `\1`.

[See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/yN3hS0/1)